# How to create 'Jeep stick shift' shape?

Tags: modeling

I have been redirected to Stack Exchange from Stack Overflow to ask my question.

I am relatively new to blender and have been working on my first blender project for a while now. I have come across this shape and I am kind of baffled at how I would go about creating it.

[image: Jeep stick shift]

I have no trouble creating the actual stick except for that weird shape below the stick that looks almost like a rounded pyramid.

Thank you for your time and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118460/whats-the-fastest-least-destructive-and-most-scalable-way-to-create-a-step-py/118467#118467

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a plane in edit mode.

[image]

Then, scale it along the y axis until it is slightly longer than it is wide. Exit edit mode with TAB and then press CTRL + 2 to add a subsurf modifier. Adjust length and width with the scale commands until it looks like the base of the "pyramid". Add edge loops by pressing CTRL + R and sliding to make the sides flatter. Scale the two end edges to make it rounder. See the first picture for the end result. Then, press I to inset faces into the shape. Use extrude (e) and scale (s) to build up the shape. Remember, you can use e+s to extrude the shape outwards. My example isn't awesome, but I also didn't pay a whole lot of attention to proportions. You could easily do better than me! :)

[image: Final result]